# How was Obito able to use Kamui immediately after awakening his MS?

Tags: naruto

In Episode 435 of *Naruto Shippuden*, Obito awakens his Mangekyo Sharingan and attacks the hidden mist ninja using the MS ability. However, he had no prior knowledge about the MS as Madara never explained it to him at this point.

So, how did Obito know about the Kamui Dimension after he suddenly awakened his MS? Madara never said that it can be a MS ability, nor Zetsu told him anything.
Also, Kakashi figured about the Kamui much later. How did Obito figure out how to use the ability without training?

Comment: There is a pattern in Naruto where users sort of subconsciously learn the basics of whatever ability they newly awakened/received. This isn't proven or stated anywhere, but it's just a pattern that I noticed. For example Kakashi and his perfect susanoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the fight against the Hidden Mist ninja after Rin's death, he never teleports his entire body to the Kamui dimension. **His intangibility ability is probably activated involuntarily** (he never got attacked unless he purposely made himself tangible, like the fight against Minato). Kakashi doesn't have intangibility, so he wouldn't know how his MS worked until he figures out how to use Kamui.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory that when a user awakens a new ability or gains a new ability, they subconsciously learn basic control over it. For example, Kakashi was able to create a perfect susanoo even though he had never had experience using it before. All he had were Obito's eyes.

Answer (score -1):

The plain answer and truth is this: it was nonsense.

Obito should not have a mastery of his MS right when he activated it. Obito was never hailed as a genius or smart, he just had a lot of Hashirama's chakra. The fact that he was able to use his MS ability right away and Kakashi wasn't able to until *part two Naruto* is utter nonsense, no other explanation.

Comment: Please refrain from using any expletives even though it's shortened, such as "bs".